# height y width VS block-size e inline-size

Tags: html, css

Hola buenas tardes estimados. Estaba realizando una prueba de código comparando los estilos, como indica el titulo width y height / block-size e inline-size.

Por un lado hice un caja (digamos .box2) y le proporcione unos estilos, exactamente los mismos que le otorgue a la otra caja (digamos .box3). Mi duda surge a partir de que cuando desactivo los padding y border me mueve las cajas hacia abajo en caso de desactivarle esas propiedades (padding y border) a una de las cajas, en cambio cuando se las desactivo a las dos cajas vuelve a su posición habitual.

Adjunto imágenes con los ejemplos para que se entienda un poco mejor.
Gracias de antemano por leerme y ayudarme con esta duda que tengo, abrazo!!

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

[image: Imagen 3]

[image: Imagen 4]

```css
.box{
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 5px solid black;
border-radius: 10%;
background: url(img/barco.jpg) center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
h2{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);
color: white;
font-size: 44px;
text-align: center;
}
.box2{
display: inline-block;
background-color: bisque;
box-sizing: border-box;
inline-size: 350px;
block-size: 200px;
border-inline: 10px groove grey;
border-block: 10px groove grey;
padding-block: 20px;
padding-inline: 20px;
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
.box3{
display: inline-block;
background-color: orangered;
width: 350px;
height: 200px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 10px double grey;
padding: 20px;
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Backgrounds and Borders: Task 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="box">
      <h2>box</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">box2</div>
    <div class="box3">box3</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Comparte el código para reproducir el asunto

Comment: Deberías echar un vistazo a [*Mastering margin collapsing*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). Básicamente lo que está ocurriendo es que los márgenes de ambos elementos colapsan entre sí.